# Function not outputting as desired/expected

Tags: python, function, ant, dictionary

I'm coding the background for a Langton Ant simulator, however the problem I'm having won't require knowledge of the problem itself, so don't worry.

Useful information would include: the variable 'grid' always corresponds to some list of lists , such as:

```
grid = [['black', 'black'], ['white', 'black'],['black', 'white']]
```

Also, I have the following 2 dictionaries defined already:

```
Dict_White= {'North':'East','East':'South','South':'West','West':'North'} 


Dict_Black= {'North':'West','West':'South','South':'East','East':'North'}
```

This is the function that is bugging me:

```
def orientation_and_colour_change(ant_row,ant_col,orientation):
   if grid[ant_row][ant_col]=='Black':
      grid[ant_row][ant_col]='White'
      orientation=Dict_Black[orientation]
   elif grid[ant_row][ant_col]=='White':
      grid[ant_row][ant_col]='Black' 
      orientation=Dict_White[orientation]
   return orientation
```

It's pretty clear what the intended use of the function is, which is to take in the 'position' and 'orientation' within the grid, and output its new orientation, which is essentially just the value for the key in the dictionary. Additionally, it should adjust one of the grid entries itself, ie 'black' to 'white' or 'white' to 'black'. However, the problems that I am  having are as follows:

The orientation return is always the same as the input, and is clearly not being passed through the function to return the value of the dictionary, rather than the input Key.

Secondly, the function is not editing the predefined grid as expected.

Any idea why these issues are occurring?

EDIT: It was a simple capital letter vs non capital letter inequality issue. Will leave the above unedited as proof of my negligence. Cheers Peter DeGlopper!

Comment: Is that your live code?  If so, you have a case mismatch - 'black' in your `grid` definition vs equality testing against 'Black' in your function.  Neither `if` condition is satisfied, so no changes are made and `orientation` is returned unchanged.

Comment: Wooooow!That fixed it! Can't believe after all that, it was just a capital letter issue. Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all your info is correct, your problem is case ("black" vs. "Black").

As an aside, this works better:

```
directions = dict(
    white={'North':'East','East':'South','South':'West','West':'North'},
    black={'North':'West','West':'South','South':'East','East':'North'},
)

def orientation_and_colour_change(ant_row,ant_col,orientation):
    "Return new orientation, and change grid state as a side effect."
    color = grid[ant_row][ant_col]
    grid[ant_row][ant_col] = 'white' if color == 'black' else 'black'
    return directions[color][orientation]
```

Comment: If I had `orientation=directions[color][orientation]`, and then `return orientation` would that now set orientation as assigned to the new direction? Because I now want to use the new orientation and pass it through a second function...

Comment: “orientation” is a local name, and thus no. Give the other function ALSO that parameter, and nest calls “f(…, orientation=g(…))”. Also, the whole thing should be a class, then the side-effects on "grid" wouldn't be a code smell (i.e. use “self.grid = ...”).

Answer (score 0):

You should try "if grid[ant_row][ant_col]=='black':" and NOT "if grid[ant_row][ant_col]=='Black':". Same thing for "elif grid[ant_row][ant_col]=='White':". Same thing when you are doing the assignment as well.